# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') and screen going blank when using map method?

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I am getting an error that turns my screen blank every time I try to render a .map method. It is supposed to pass down the search results and render the result list. Here's my code (also for easier readability here is the link to my github (https://github.com/jackkayak/Jammer) which has the other components where I might have gone wrong):

```
import React from "react";
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
                {
                    this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                        return <Track track={track} key={track.id}/>
                                        
                    })
                }
</div>

        )
    }
}

export default TrackList;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In `Playlist.js` you don't pass any props to `<TrackList />`

Comment: It would be this.props. what exactly?

Comment: It would be `<TrackList tracks={/*data here /*} />` I don't know where do you have these tracks. You probably forgot to pass props to `<PlayList />` also

Comment: Yea you were right, i ended up just deleting the tracklist call and it worked again. Thanks for pointing it out